# С чего начать программировать android зная только c#

Tags: c#, android

Здравствуйте, есть необходимость создать программу на андроид. Программировал только на c#.
Нашёл пока http://xamarin.com/ и http://www.dot42.com/.

Как-то не очень хочется сразу учить Java. Можно ли в этих оболочках (или других) программировать, что лучше и может кто-то находил русскоязычную информацию по разработке на c#.

Спасибо большое.

Comment: плохо ищешь.. полно инфы

Comment: начните с изучения Java. Так будет легче.

Comment: Не бойтесь менять язык. Если будет время почитайте http://habrahabr.ru/post/172277/

Comment: Так а чем моно и dot42 то вас не устраивают?

Comment: Все не так плохо, как кажется. Попробуй погуглить Xamarin и MonoDroid. Тебе понравится!

Answer (score 3):

Скажем так, утешить вас особо нечем. Если прям вообще не хотите учить Java, то придется довольствоваться тем, что есть, а именно - официальной документацией от Xamarin и одной-двумя книгами по данной теме (разработка под Android на c#, я имею в виду). То и другое - на английском. На русском найдете в лучшем случае пару статей на Хабре и и десяток-другой одинаковых хелловорлдов от школьников. Это неудивительно - продукт от Xamarin молод (даже по меркам платформы, которая сама по себе древней не является) и не факт, что вырастет во что-то серьезное. 
Если все же захотите учить Java, то к вашим услугам уже куда больше литературы и соответствующих ресурсов в интернете, в том числе и на русском. Более того, если вы хотите быть сколько-нибудь хорошим программистом, то знать английский хотя бы на уровне чтения технической документации знать просто обязательно.

Словом, подытоживая вышесказанное, если вам действительно это нужно, то придется чем-то пожертвовать - либо учить Java, либо  учить английский. Лучше, конечно, и то и другое